# Why this date conversion with Pandas.to_datetime is much slower than some alternatives?

Tags: python, pandas

Performing a performance profiling, I was quite surprised to identidy `pd.to_datetime` as a large drag to performance (62sec spent out of 91sec in my use case). So I may not be using the function as I should.

Simple example case, I need to convert `timestamp = 623289600000000000L` in a date/timestamp format.

```
import datetime
import time
import pandas as pd
timestamp = 623289600000000000L

timeit pd.to_datetime(timestamp, unit = 'ns')
10000 loops, best of 3: 46.9 us per loop

In [3]: timeit time.ctime(timestamp/10**9)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 904 ns per loop

timeit time.localtime(timestamp/10**9)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.13 us per loop

timeit datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp/10**9)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.51 us per loop

timeit datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp/10**9)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.29 us per loop
```

I awware these functions each returns a different object, however `pd.to_datetime` is by far the slowest. Is that expected?

I now use `datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp` in my code and it works fine. However, I would have rather keep using Pandas. Plus Pandas handles fine pre-1970 dates (see below). Would you be able to provide some guidance?

`pd.to_datetime` has one advantage: it support negative input / pre-1970-01-01 dates. That is also quite important for my use case.

```
timestamp =-445645400000000000L
pd.to_datetime(timestamp, unit = 'ns')
Timestamp('1955-11-18 01:36:40', tz=None)

datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp/10**9)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-9-99b040d30a3e>", line 1, in <module>
    datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp/10**9)

ValueError: timestamp out of range for platform localtime()/gmtime() function
```

I use Python 2.7.5 and Pandas 0.12.0 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to_datetime is going to parse the timestamp argument in several ways to find out what is the timestamp inside. It is useful to convert strings representing datetime into Timestamp objects.

If the data you are manipulating is already a timestamp int, you can directly call the Timestamp object to build it:

```
pd.Timestamp(timestamp)
Out[51]: Timestamp('1989-10-02 00:00:00', tz=None)

%timeit pd.Timestamp(timestamp)
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.96 µs per loop
```

It will also work with negative numbers:

```
pd.Timestamp(-445645400000000000L)
Out[54]: Timestamp('1955-11-18 01:36:40', tz=None)
```

Comment: `pd.Timestamp`, the function I needed. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 4):

Dateparsing in pandas with the following function make things really quick, if you have duplicate datetime values to convert.

Benchmarks:

```
$ python date-parse.py
to_datetime: 5799 ms
dateutil:    5162 ms
strptime:    1651 ms
manual:       242 ms
lookup:        32 ms

def lookup(s):
    """
    This is an extremely fast approach to datetime parsing.
    For large data, the same dates are often repeated. Rather than
    re-parse these, we store all unique dates, parse them, and
    use a lookup to convert all dates.
    """
    dates = {date:pd.to_datetime(date) for date in s.unique()}
    return s.apply(lambda v: dates[v])
```

And, the [source.](https://github.com/sanand0/benchmarks/tree/master/date-parse)

Comment: Beware. In the benchmark source, `s = pd.Series(['01-31-2012']*100000)`, so YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Converting a single timestamp is not a valid comparison, and is just a measure of the number of function calls.

```
In [9]: arr = [timestamp] * 1000000

In [10]: %timeit pd.to_datetime(arr,unit='ns')
1 loops, best of 3: 234 ms per loop

In [12]: arr = (np.array(arr)/10**9).tolist()

In [13]: %timeit [ time.ctime(x) for x in arr ]
1 loops, best of 3: 1.6 s per loop

In [31]: f = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp

In [32]: %timeit [ f(x) for x in arr ]
1 loops, best of 3: 643 ms per loop
```

Its clear that using a vectorized approach is MUCH faster when applied to a non-trivial data set.

Comment: Jeff, I cannot used a vectorized approach: I receive these timestamps as a stream of event to be processed in sequence.

Comment: The task I was performing is now 7s instead of 62s. Plus user Boud advised I use `pd.Timestamp` instead of `pd.to_datetime`. I am now performing the same task 9 times quicker and using a much more suitable function: I believe it was worth asking the question :-)